# display : block stretches link width

Tags: css

I don't know why but when I set my CSS for an `<img>` to `display: inline` it works fine.

But then I wrote `display: block;` and it was stretching the link wrapped around the element, across the entire screen.

Comment: To start, you don't have a valid doctype and are using deprecated elements.

Answer (score 2):

Block elements take up the full width available, with a new line before and after since the anchor tag is enclosing it it is also going full width.

Inline elements take up only as much width is needed and doesn't force new lines.

To fix it, you should wrap your "my work on instagram" anchor tag and image in a div, which is a block element, and it will not stretch the internal elements. Also, remove the `display:block` from your instawork class in your css. [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JmnRW/)

```
<div><a href="http://www.instagram.com/pauldewar_me" target="blank_"><img src="http://www.pauldewar.me/imgs/instawork.png"></a></div>
```

Reference: [CSS Blocks vs Inline CSS Display Styles](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/)

Comment: an idea how to fix it? :-)

Comment: Let me know if that fixes it for you.